# CGImage has no properties / metadata (CGImageProperties)

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-graphics, cgimage

Say I have a `CGImage` that was loaded from some `URL`, and I want to extract its properties via `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex`:

```swift
// Playground

import SwiftUI

func printPropertiesOf(_ image: CGImage) {
    guard let dataProvider = image.dataProvider else {
        print("Couldn't get the data provider.")
        return
    }
    guard let data = dataProvider.data else {
        print("Couldn't get the data.")
        return
    }
    guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data, nil) else {
        print("Couldn't get the source.")
        return
    }
    guard let properties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil) else {
        print("Couldn't get the properties.")
        return
    }
    print(properties)
}

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Landscape/Landscape_0", withExtension: "jpg")!
let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil)!
let cgImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, nil)!

printPropertiesOf(cgImage)
```

**Output:**

> Couldn't get the properties.

---

But if I use the `URL` where the image resides, instead of the `CGImage`:

```swift
// Playground

import SwiftUI

func printPropertiesOfImageIn(_ url: URL) {
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
        print("Couldn't get the data.")
        return
    }
    guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil) else {
        print("Couldn't get the source.")
        return
    }
    guard let properties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil) else {
        print("Couldn't get the properties.")
        return
    }
    print(properties)
}

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Landscape/Landscape_0", withExtension: "jpg")!
let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil)!
let cgImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, nil)!

printPropertiesOfImageIn(url)
```

**Output:**

```
{
    ColorModel = RGB;
    DPIHeight = 72;
    DPIWidth = 72;
    Depth = 8;
    PixelHeight = 1200;
    PixelWidth = 1800;
    "{JFIF}" =     {
        DensityUnit = 1;
        JFIFVersion =         (
            1,
            0,
            1
        );
        XDensity = 72;
        YDensity = 72;
    };
    "{TIFF}" =     {
        Orientation = 0;
        ResolutionUnit = 2;
        XResolution = 72;
        YResolution = 72;
    };
}
```

---

> Is there a way to retrieve the metadata from a `CGImage` itself,
>   without having to rely on its source URL?
>
> If not, is there a way to find out the source `URL` of a given
>   `CGImage`?

(Note: the image used in the above examples [can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd8NU.jpg).)

Comment: URL is just the address where the resource data is saved. You won't find that information inside the file itself.

Comment: I see. So giving that I would have only a `CGImage` to work with, would there be any way to extract its metadata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CGImage` should be completely raw bitmap data. A minimum set of uncompressed data to visually present an image even. From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage) "A bitmap image or image mask".

I am actually surprised that you were able to construct a source using `CGImageSourceCreateWithData` in two such different ways:

- In first case you are creating it directly from raw uncompressed data which is your `CGImage`. It is expected that it has absolutely no headers or additional information on how it should be shown.
- In second case you are creating it from JPEG data which is compressed data with headers that may contain a lot of different information. Some of the info may be completely unrelated such as coordinates of where image was taken or date it was taken on for instance.

So the additional information that you are showing in second case could potentially be used by the system to construct a `CGImage` object (encoding for instance). But it is not the information that needs to be appended to `CGImage` in order to display it since it is already prepared (decoded) for presentation.

In your title you are saying "CGImage has no properties / metadata (CGImageProperties)". There is no such thing as "CGImageProperties", there is "CGImageSourceProperties". So it is the source that has the properties.

So I believe these properties are not copied and there is no way to get them from `CGImage` alone. There are other properties you can get directly from `CGImage` though:

- cgImage.width
- cgImage.height
- cgImage.alphaInfo
- cgImage.bitmapInfo
- cgImage.bitsPerComponent
- cgImage.colorSpace
- ...

You can check a bit more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage?language=swift).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding `CGImageProperties`, Apple seems to point to it in the documentation of `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex`; That is: `A dictionary that contains the properties associated with the image. See CGImageProperties for a list of properties that can be in the dictionary.` Documentation on `CGImageProperties`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimageproperties But perhaps that doesn't apply here, then.

Comment: @backslash-f well it does. But this is what I tried to explain with the "source" part. The function checks the image SOURCE for properties. But the image source when it is `CGImage` will have no properties. When it is a JPEG it will have properties. That is the difference. A bit confusing for sure. But when you create a `CGImage` object you lose all the properties. Then you create a new source out of your `CGImage` object instead of the JPEG so you lose it all... I guess you could do `guard let data = UIImage(cgImage: image).jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)` in your first example...

Comment: ...but I would not expect that result will be always OK. You may lose a lot of info in the process and only expect some default Apple information that is being put into that data set.

Comment: That makes sense. Since this is a cross-platform app, I'm trying to use `CoreGraphics` / `ImageIO` exclusively (i.e. I'm trying to avoid stuff from `UIImage`). Well, it is what it is... I'm accepting your answer. 

Comment: @backslash-f that sounds reasonable. But why did you not like your second example which uses the URL directly? If you ask me that sounds like the best solution.

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably going that route. I was trying to avoid having to bring the source `URL` all the way to this module that ideally would work only with `CGImage`s. But it's not that bad... Just a little bit of extra work. 